# Ask if userinput was right y/n in C

Tags: c

I want to use the following script in my c program.
the user will be able to input an IP. after that i want to be sure, the input was right and ask the user

```
char eingabe;

printf("Is that the right input? y/n: ");

scanf("%s",&eingabe);
printf("your input was: %s\n", eingabe);

if(eingabe == 'y') {
    printf("you klicked y");
} else {
    printf("you clicked no");
}
```

Comment: you are using character variable eingabe and in printf  and scanf function you are using format specifier of string %s for that..... Can you please check the code ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%s",&eingabe);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&eingabe);
```

and

```
printf("your input was: %s\n", eingabe);
```

to

```
printf("your input was: %c\n", eingabe);
```

because `%c` is the right format specifier for a `char`. `%s` is the format specifier for a string. The space before `%c` in the `scanf` skips any number of whitespace characters(`' '`,`\n` etc) includeing none before scanning a character(`%c`).